# Removed battery while phone plugged in

Tags: battery

I accidentally removed the battery from LG G3 while plugged in and charging, does this damage the battery or the phone?

Comment: When you removed the battery did the phone stay on or did it instantly went off? As long as device did not went off but stayed on I don't see a problem.

Comment: It turned off and show a battery with exclamation mark inside

Comment: Removing power from a running phone may damage a lot especially if there were write operations active on flash memory at that moment.

Comment: that won't damage anything because it's not unusual for smartphones that battery runs out of power. journaling file system can handle such emmc writing failures very well. powering smartphone without battery is a different story. most ac chargers won't deliver stable dc current that's why power is only used for charging, while phone is powered by battery only. therefore it should make no difference if charger was connected at the time of battery removal or not